# Are there any commands showing Apple File System (APFS) timestamps in nanoseconds?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystems, macos-high-sierra, apfs

I heard that [timestamps in APFS are in nanoseconds](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/VolumeFormatComparison/VolumeFormatComparison.html).

Are there any commands that are able to show APFS timestamps in nanoseconds?

I've tried `ls`, `stat` but no luck so far.

Comment: are you try this: `echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))` just run this command in your terminal

Comment: @YaseenAhmad Running your command results in this error: `bash: 1508845153N: value too great for base (error token is "1508845153N")`. What I want to know is not current time but timestamps of files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get nanosecond timestamps by requesting floating point output:

```
% stat -f %Fm foo
1609297230.485880489
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no commands, but you can create a simple C program to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    struct stat attr;
    stat("/path/to/file", &attr);
    printf("Last modified time: %ld", (long)attr.st_mtimespec.tv_nsec);
}
```

Comment: That should likely read `(long)attr.st_mtimespec.tv_nsec` - no point in printing the address of the value...